# How to override interface in a function and maintain the correct return type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, zod

I have a definePlugin function that accepts an object implementing the PluginConfig interface, with a default RequestValidator. I’m trying to override this interface, providing a custom validator while ensuring the returned value has the correct type. However, my current implementation results in the returned vueAuth having the type any. How do I override the interface while maintaining the correct return type?
Here’s my current code:

```
import { z } from 'zod'

// Create de default validator
export const EmailValidator = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({ required_error: 'auth.validation.email' })
    .email({ message: 'auth.validation.email_format' })
})

// The default interface the generic should at least implement
interface PluginConfig {
  validator?: z.ZodType
}

// The default interface with the default validator to use if not overriden
interface DefaultPluginConfig {
  validator?: typeof EmailValidator
}

const definePlugin = <T extends PluginConfig = DefaultPluginConfig>({
  validator = EmailValidator
}: T) => {
  return validator.parse({})
}

const test = definePlugin({})
// Object should look like EmailValidator but is any instead
test.email

// Create a custom validator
const CustomValidator = z.object({
  email: z.string(),
  username: z.string()
})

// Create a custom interface to use as generic
interface CustomConfig {
  validator?: typeof CustomValidator
}

const test2 = definePlugin<CustomConfig>({
  validator: CustomValidator
})
// Object should look like CustomValidator but is any instead
test2.username
test2.username
```

What changes should I make to ensure that definePlugin has the correct type when providing a custom validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in your code which cause problem:

1. You have defined `PluginConfig` to property `z.ZodType` which is a type not a value. You can modify as:

   interface PluginConfig {
   validator?: z.Schema;
   }
2. In your code your `DefaultPluginConfig` interface is not properly extending `PluginConfig`. You can change this as:

   interface DefaultPluginConfig extends PluginConfig {
   validator?: typeof EmailValidator;
   }

Your code would look like:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

// Create the default validator
export const EmailValidator = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({ required_error: 'auth.validation.email' })
    .email({ message: 'auth.validation.email_format' }),
});

// The default interface the generic should at least implement
interface PluginConfig {
  validator?: z.Schema<any>;
}

// The default interface with the default validator to use if not overridden
interface DefaultPluginConfig extends PluginConfig {
  validator?: typeof EmailValidator;
}

const definePlugin = <T extends PluginConfig = DefaultPluginConfig>({
  validator = EmailValidator,
}: T) => {
  return validator.parse({});
};

const test = definePlugin({});
test.email; // Object has the correct type EmailValidator

// Create a custom validator
const CustomValidator = z.object({
  email: z.string(),
  username: z.string(),
});

// Create a custom interface to use as generic
interface CustomConfig extends PluginConfig {
  validator?: typeof CustomValidator;
}

const test2 = definePlugin<CustomConfig>({
  validator: CustomValidator,
});
test2.username; // Object has the correct type CustomValidator
test2.email; // Object has the correct type CustomValidator (from CustomValidator)
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

**UPDATED CODE (FINAL)**:

As per discussion on chat the correct answer is:

```
import { z, ZodType } from "zod";

// Create the default validator
export const EmailValidator = z.object({
  email: z.string().default("")
});

// The default interface the generic should at least implement
interface PluginConfig<T extends ZodType = typeof EmailValidator> {
  validator?: T;
}

const definePlugin = <
  T extends PluginConfig = PluginConfig<typeof EmailValidator>,
  R = T extends PluginConfig<infer V> ? V : ZodType
>({
  validator = EmailValidator
}: T): R extends ZodType<infer P> ? P : never => {
  return validator.parse({}) as any;
};

const test = definePlugin({});
test.email; // Object has the correct type EmailValidator

const CustomValidator = z.object({
  email: z.string().default(""),
  username: z.string().default("")
});

type CustomConfig = PluginConfig<typeof CustomValidator>;

const test2 = definePlugin<CustomConfig>({
  validator: CustomValidator
});

console.log(test2.username);
```

So here **Generic V and P** are used to capture the types from `PluginConfig` and `ZodType` respectively.

Here,
`V` - represents inferred types of validator property in PluginConfig
`P` - represents the inferred type of the ZodType

These generics `V` and `P` allow the function to handle different validator configurations and return suitable inferred type based on it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! for me `test` and `test2` are still `any` though. I use typescript 5.1.3. This does work in Webstorm with typescript version 4.8.4.

Comment: @andredewaard Okay got it. Okay I have a solution for that , so basically i will explicitly assert the type of the validator property in test2 using the as keyword to ensure proper type inference.Do you need that code or you understand what to do  ? Can I change ?

Comment: I have added code above !! Hope this help and please let me know if you still face any issue . Happy coding :)

Comment: in your latest example test2 stays of type `EmailValidator ` and typescript throws an error on `test2.username`

Comment: Can you share the full error line. I will help you in more clearly after  knowing exact error.

Comment: Okay I get little bit, so in the updated code  I added `withTypeAssertion`  to perform the type assertion. I hope it works well. Please let me know if it still gives issue. Also if error comes please provide the exact error as it is produced in your system. It really helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks for your time, however this throws a whole list of errors. where this one is the most important I guess: `Argument of type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ZodType<any, ZodTypeDef, any>'.
  Type '{ email: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ZodType<any, ZodTypeDef, any>': _type, _output, _input, _def, and 31 more.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254031/discussion-between-andre-de-waard-and-jagroop).

Answer (score 0):

1. The basic solution is to `z.infer`

```
const definePlugin = <T extends PluginConfig = DefaultPluginConfig>({
  validator = EmailValidator
}: T): z.infer<NonNullable<T['validator']>> => {
  return validator.parse({})
}
```

This will work fine with provided generic parameter, but will fail to provide a default

---

2. Overloads are the best way to work with call corner cases, as they have order of inference tries. I would recommend to use them.

```
function definePlugin({validator}: DefaultPluginConfig): z.infer<NonNullable<DefaultPluginConfig['validator']>>;
function definePlugin<T extends PluginConfig>({validator}: T): z.infer<NonNullable<T['validator']>>;
function definePlugin({validator = EmailValidator}: PluginConfig) {
  return validator.parse({})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. First option gives me an unknown object though, and the second option is not really an option for me since I want to use this in multiple projects where every project could potentially use a different object and I don't want to recreate a new function every time.